# Change the size of a Form depending on the size of child Label

Tags: vb.net, winforms, autosize

How would you change the Form size depending on the width/length of a Label?

I need to resize a Form depending on how much text there is in a Label (the text is automatically generated from case statements).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to put the `AutoSize` to True of the `Form`

Open the `Form` and put a `Label` on it , the Label gets a Name lets say `Label1`.
[image]

Rightclick on the Form and open Properties
[image]

Then Choose AutoSize to True

[image]

Then return to the Form and dubbleclick on the Form this case Form1, Form1.vb is open.

In `Form1_Load`if it is another Label you have to adjust it to the right Name:

```
  Label1.Text = "This is a example text and a bit longer zo the form is getting bigger"
```

[image]

Run it and there it is :

[image]

Look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.autosize?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Comment: I don't think that this is the problem because autosize wouldn't really have anything to do with a label.

Comment: I update my answer , there are are a lots of ways on google . This is the easy one

Comment: I don't really get how to do it, I've only done Visual Basic for about a week.

Comment: Oke no problem , i put some image's how to make it work . I use Visual Studio 2017 but in this case it is the same as newer versions

Comment: @CantthinkofaUsername . If the answer is the right solution for you, please click the ✔ to accept the answer